# Apply CSS to certain product thumbnails only

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, css

I'm running a WooCommerce site and found a new way of importing product images and need to apply CSS to thumbnail pictures **of new products only** and leave old products untouched.

Looking at the source code, I found each product has a product ID:

```
<li class="product type-product post-100 data-product-id="100">
```

Is there any way to apply CSS to, let's say, data-product-id > 100? E.g.

```
if (data-product-id > 100) {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

Either by using a third party plugin or add custom JS/CSS code?

Comment: Plugin recommendations are offtopic here, and CSS questions should go on stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

Can you just specify a new class when you create those thumbnails, and style accordingly?

If this is what you want to do:

You need to grab every element that has the `[data-id]` attribute into an object array
`var ids = document.querySelectorAll("[data-id]");`

Then you need to iterate over them, and check the value:

```
ids.forEach((el) => {
        if (parseInt(el.dataset.id) > 100) {
            el.classList.add("new-style");
        }
    });
```

You can add the new styling in your CSS (so you can change it as needed without touching the js)

You want to wrap the js in a document ready so the elements are there before it starts, or it'll return undefined.

The final code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var ids = document.querySelectorAll("[data-id]");

    ids.forEach((el) => {
        if (parseInt(el.dataset.id) > 100) {
            el.classList.add("new-product");
        }
    });
});
```

Then you can target the new products using `.new-product{}` in your CSS files.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, Joel! The first point is actually very good, I should have thought of that. It should be easier adding a new class to newer products (or to the old ones, excluding them from the new styling) than adding custom JS code. Do you know an easy way to add classes on product level?

Comment: Depends on how you're adding them, and how many old products you have. You may be able to add a class to the items *as* you add them depending on how you're importing it.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I was able to solve it by adding a product tag to all old products and excluding it from the new styling: .new-product:not(.product-tag-oldproduct) {}

Comment: Perfect! Glad you got it sorted! You should probably amend/add your own answer so that people who have this issue will find it as well. I'm also more than happy to expand *my* answer to make it applicable to your solution so that those find it as well. It's up to you. ;)